# How to set DataFormatString to Textbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `Datagrid` and I have bound column as below

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}">
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundColumn>
```

I want to use above dataformat string for below `TextBox`.

```
<asp:TextBox  DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00}" ID="textbox1" runat="server" MaxLength="150"></asp:TextBox>
```

If I try to set Dataformatstring to `TextBox` it is not working. How can I add dataformatstring to `TextBox` in ASP.NET or **Javascript** code in order to to same issue?

Comment: Short answer not possible. Because `DataFormatString`  is the [BoundFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) proerty.

Comment: Where you set TextBox.Text value? In code behind or in aspx side with Eval?

Comment: If possible javascript it will solve problem too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `TextBox.Text` value in code behind, you can do like this:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", yourValue);
```

Check it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZUwv5)

If you set in aspx side, you can with `Eval`:

```
<asp:TextBox  Text='<%# Eval("myField", "{0:#,##0.00}") %>' ID="textbox1" runat="server" MaxLength="150"></asp:TextBox>
```